# We're sorry, but something went wrong When Deploying Rails App to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My Rails 3 app is fully functional when running on my local dev environment. However, after I push to Heroku I get this cryptic error in red "We're sorry, but something went wrong" I did some research and tried the following steps with no luck:

1. I made sure sqlite3 was in a dev group and PostgreSQL was in prod.
2. In my config/environment/prod.rb, I changed `config.assets.compile` from `false` to `true`
3. After pushing to Heroku, I ran `heroku run rake db:migrate`, which executed successfully.
4. I noticed that the precompile was failing during the push to Heroku so I precompiled locally via `rake assets:precompile`.
5. When I run `heroku ps`, it shows that the dyno is up `[web.1: up 2013/08/27 10:52:23 (~ 2m ago)]`
6. Lastly, I reviewed the logs and see no sign of a failure or error.

I included my log and gem files below as well as part of the results from running heroku logs --tail. I appreciate any suggestions or other help. Thanks

tail -- logs

```
 Started GET "/" for 98.204.192.25 at 2013-08-27 19:54:28 +0000
 Processing by StoreController#index as HTML
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 18ms
 36m2013-08-27T19:54:28.623752+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
 ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template store/index,    application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb,  :builder]}. Searched in: * "/app/app/views"* "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.0.3/app/views"

# Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1' #used to make sample users with names and email
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3' #paginate functionality
gem "jquery-rails", "2.3.0"
gem 'devise'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'thin'

# Gems used only for assets and not required in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

# Development only gems
group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end

# Dev and Test Gems
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Heroku Gems
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Heroku logs

```
$ heroku ps
=== web (1X): `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p $PORT`
web.1: up 2013/08/27 10:52:23 (~ 2m ago)

$ heroku logs
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089286+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089286+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089286+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089286+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090025+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__4156855088543667456__process_action__706269566432664392__callbacks'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090025+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089463+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090025+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090025+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090025+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090025+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090025+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090025+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090025+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090197+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090197+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090025+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090197+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090197+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090197+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090197+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090197+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090197+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090197+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090197+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090589+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090775+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090775+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090775+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090775+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090775+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090775+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090775+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090775+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090775+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.090775+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091150+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091150+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091150+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4096359245755012766__call__2028039068216007955__callbacks'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091150+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091150+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091150+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091150+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091150+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091150+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091150+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091319+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connectioncontext.rb:51:in `call'.rb:63:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091655+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.092315+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.091817+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.092315+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.092315+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.092315+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[36m2013-08-27T14:53:48.092315+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m
←[33m2013-08-27T14:53:48.089155+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path=/ host=fast-island-8704.herokuapp.com fwd="98.204.192.25" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=22ms status=500 bytes=643
←[33m2013-08-27T14:52:41.003446+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m at=info method=GET path=/ host=fast-island-8704.herokuapp.com fwd="98.204.192.25" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=278ms status=500 bytes=643
```

Comment: I don't know how you copied the heroku logs, but they are full of things like ←[33m, which are ansi sequences to color the output. Moreover, there are plenty of spurious spaces. All this makes it nearly impossible to read. One thing I could detect, was a 'missing method', which probably also appears on your local run. (try to copy the logs from a terminal window)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the formatting on your logs, but can't see the part that is causing the error. It looks like your application is starting properly, but something is causing an error when you access the web page. Try running `heroku logs --tail`, then watch the output as you request the page. Towards the top of the request in the logs, you should see the part of your application that is having an issue. It should start with `app/...` instead of `vendor/bundle/...`. Once you have that, you (or I) can further diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. i ran the logs --tail and noticed the following issue with one of my view templates:
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template store/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in: * "/app/app/views"
* "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.0.3/app/views"   i am  not sure why it wouldnt find store/index its on my local. i tried pushing it up to git again but still no luck. any suggestions?

Comment: i think i see what the problem is but not sure how to fix it. when i try to commit app/views/store git returns a (modified content, untracked content) message. how do i set this to being tracked?

Comment: Try running `git add app/views/store && git commit -m "Add store views."`.

Comment: thats not it i think it has something to do with subcommits not sure how to fix it though. when i run git show this is what i get Date:   Tue Aug 27 18:09:24 2013 -0400
    pushing store index
diff --git a/app/views/layouts b/app/views/layouts
index 0c98dd7..7a6a94b 160000
--- a/app/views/layouts
+++ b/app/views/layouts
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 0c98dd75ada83a37606850c10cdb01327743bb24
+Subproject commit 7a6a94b2a901252e5bf8554ca7184bb128948e1a
diff --git a/app/views/store b/app/views/store
:

Comment: got it to work had to blew out and reinitialize my git repository.. thanks for the insight on tailing the logs